# Can Ubuntu on Nexus 7 run desktop Ubuntu programs?

Tags: nexus-7

I'm thinking about getting an Ubuntu on Nexus 7 and I have one question: programs that runs on Ubuntu Desktop (like Steam, that have support for linux, or game's for linux) will work?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean Ubuntu for Tablets, I think no. As it said [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/devices/tablet/partner) for hardware requirements a 7-inch tablet can’t provide a full desktop convergence.